# Passing a member function as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a hash table class. It has a template parameter `hashFunction`:

```
#include <string>

template<class KeyType> using hashFunction_t = size_t(size_t, const KeyType&);

template< class KeyType, class ValueType, int nHashGroups,
    hashFunction_t<KeyType> hashFunction >
class HashTable
{

};

class Entity
{
    //djb2
    size_t stringHash(size_t nGroups, const std::string& key)
    {
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        const char* str = key.c_str();

        int c = 0;
        while (c = *str++)
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;

        return hash % nGroups;
    }

    HashTable <std::string, int, 10, stringHash> ht; 
};

int main()
{
    Entity{};
}
```

I would prefer to hide `stringHash` function inside the `Entity` class as a private function but doing that gives me an error:

```
Error (active)  E0458   argument of type 
"size_t (Entity::*)(size_t nGroups, const std::string &key)" 
is incompatible with template parameter of type 
"hashFunction_t<std::string> *"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems that you declared the function as a non-`static` member function. You need to make it `static` (though it would really help if you provided the actual code that fails to compile instead of one that works completely fine)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks you. That does make sense, don't know why I didn't think of that. I also changed the question.

Comment: Try typing "pass member function" in the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a pointer-to-member as a type template parameter, and this is not supported, basically because when you define a type you don't bind that type to any specific object.

When (as suggested in a comment) you make `stringHash` static, then you no longer need the object, so it can be used to define the type.

If you still need to have `stringHash` from a non-static member, then you can change the template to something like the below. Be aware that you have to pass the object to the `HashTable` in order to call the `hashFunction`. Also, keep an eye on the syntax to call it.

```cpp
template<class KeyType, class Obj> using hashFunction_t =
    size_t(Obj::*)(size_t, const KeyType&);

template< class KeyType, class ValueType, int nHashGroups,
    class Obj, hashFunction_t<KeyType, Obj> hashFunction>
class HashTable
{
public:
    explicit HashTable(Obj& obj) : m_obj{obj} {
        (m_obj.*hashFunction)(10, ""); // arguments just for illustrative purposes
    }

private:
    Obj& m_obj; // keep a reference to the object to call the method
                // be careful with dangling references
};

class Entity
{
    size_t stringHash(size_t nGroups, const std::string& key)
    /* ... */

    // Pass a reference to the object
    HashTable <std::string, int, 10, Entity, &Entity::stringHash> ht{*this};
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a lot of new syntax for me. Can you please explain how `(m_obj.*hashFunction)` is a function? Especially the * part. Is it just a syntax to remember?

Comment: Sure, basically you first dereference the function pointer (`*hashFunction`), then indicate the object to which that function is member (`m_obj.*hashFunction`, this is the pointer-to-member operator), and finally you call it with the required arguments (`(m_obj.*hashFunction)(....)`). The parenthesis are needed because the function call (`(...)`) has higher precedence than the pointer-to-member.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "reference to member function". There are only pointers.